# Swiping between webviews not possible (Windows 8)

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Currently i'm developing a WinRT app and I want to implement a swipe between webpage. I used a FlipView for the swiping.

But apparently the WebView is capturing the swipes and doesn't pass those events to the FlipView.

```
<FlipView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="50,50,50,50">
        <FlipViewItem>
            <WebView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="600" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1200" Source="http://www.site1.com" ManipulationMode="None"/>
        </FlipViewItem>
        <FlipViewItem>
            <WebView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="600" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1200" Source="http://www.site2.com"/>
        </FlipViewItem>
</FlipView>
```

Is there a way to pass the swipe events to the FlipView?

Comment: More about that: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/f50ac287-c6ee-4275-88d3-6484b03a2b85 and the WebView class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  Because the webview, unlike other controls, is technically a separate window, you run into limitations like this where it doesn't play nicely when you try to put it inside another interactive control or if you try to render other controls on top of it.  This unfortunate limitation has always plagued Microsoft's UI frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a title bar area above the WebView, and the swipe events in that area would still be passed to the FlipView.